# How to show controller response continuously in the client?

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC 3.2 I created a (JSP) webpage with a textarea. From the client I fire a console application which is executed on the server. I want to show the output of this console app in the textarea of the browser.

I do get a response that shows the cmd output of the console. However the problem is that the console output is shown all at once after the programm has finished. I want to see the each output line immediately update the textarea.

**Controller code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void Console(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C cd \"C:\\appl\"" + "&" + "consoleApp.bat");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  

    String line = null; 
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
          response.getWriter().println(line);
          response.getWriter().flush();
          logger.info(line);
      }

 }
```

**Client code**

```
$(function(){
    $('#someTag').click(function(){
        $.post("url","data",
                function(response){  
                    $('#console').append(response);     
                    var psconsole = $('#console');
                    psconsole.scrollTop(
                        psconsole[0].scrollHeight - (psconsole.height() - 10)
                    );
             });            

    });
});
```

#### **Update**

I implemented a polling mechanism (see code below). However this is a more indirect approach then I had in mind. If someone got a cleaner implementation or a simple server push example I would like to see it.

**Controller code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deploy", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String console(@RequestParam(value="request", required=false) String request) throws Exception {

    logger.info("status " + request);       

    if(request.equals("start")){
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C dir C:\\");

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        return "started";
    }      

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        logger.info(line);
        return line;
      }        

    logger.info("status finished");     
    return "finished";
 }
```

**Client code**

```
        var status = "start";
        var console = $('#console');                        

        console.append("starting" + '\r');              

        (function poll(){                   
           setTimeout(function(){
              $.ajax({ 
                  url: "deploy",
                  data: {request:  status},
                  type: "post",
                  success: function(data){     

                        if(data.indexOf("finished") !== -1){
                            console.append(data + '\r');                                
                            setTimeout(function()
                                    {console.scrollTop(console[0].scrollHeight - console.height());}
                                    , 20);                              
                            status = "finished";
                        }else if(data === ""){
                            console.append('\r');                               
                            setTimeout(function()
                                    {console.scrollTop(console[0].scrollHeight - console.height());}
                                    , 20);
                            status = "processing";                              
                            poll();                             
                        }else{
                            console.append(data + '\r');                                
                            setTimeout(function()
                                    {console.scrollTop(console[0].scrollHeight - console.height());}
                                    , 20);                              
                            status = "processing";
                            poll();
                        }                       
              }, dataType: "text"});
          }, 100);

        })();
```

Comment: You may have to use a polling mechanism to do it

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Johny, since the whole app depends on request, no request no response.

Comment: To expand on @ArunPJohny, I think you need to load a default JSP that has JavaScript to perform an async (AJAX) polling to get your console data.

Comment: The implementation should be along the lines of 1) The request handling method will start a new thread to process the request and return a key to the ajax callback, the ajax callback will send poll requests to the server with the given key to get new messages

Comment: I was self thinking of getting the response stream before success (with xhr?) or passing the interim results to another method in the controller.

Comment: You cannot just hijack the Servlet response, and because Servlets are a request/response mechinism, you have to work within those confinments.  There are tricks around this, like long polling or web sockets, but they still require a request for a response.  What @ArunPJohny suggests is the basic approach to any of these "tricks".  First you need to establish starting some long process (client asks server to run process, server says OK), then you need to repeatedly ask for updates to the status of that long process (client says "whats the status now?").  This is the "async" part of AJAX.

Comment: I understand the principle of the polling mechanism. Starting the server process is also no problem, but do you have an example on how to send the poll request and retrieve the messages?